# Is this an efficient way to check request bodies in Node?

Tags: node.js

Pretty self explanatory I think. I have a register feature, and I've followed the advice of just about every tutorial out there saying to decouple application logic from the client. So, is this server code a good way to handle making sure all the fields needed are there? Why or why not?

PS: _.contains is from the lodash library.

```
function checkBody(body, callback){
  var required = ['username', 'password', 'email'];
  for (x in required){
    if (!_.contains(body, required[x])){
      callback(null, false);
    }
  }
  callback(null, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [JSON schemas](http://json-schema.org/) to validate request bodies because it lets you enforce your requirements declaratively. You can also write a generic middleware function to keep your code nice and clean. `tv4` is a nice library for getting this done. Here's a small example:

```
var tv4 = require('tv4');

var enforceSchema = function(schema) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (!tv4.validate(req.body, schema)) {
            res.status(400).end();
        } else {
            next();
        }
    };
};

var loginSchema = {
    properties: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 1
        },
        email: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 1
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 1
        }
    },
    required: ['username', 'email', 'password']
};

app.post('/signup', enforceSchema(loginSchema), function(req, res, next) {
    res.end();
});
```